# Why Photos app is NOT showing in the Document Provider extensions on the device?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, uidocumentpickervc, document-provider

I'm working in app to pick photo, I have used `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to display list of extensions for document provider. This list shows Dropbox, iCloud, GoogleDrive but not the native Photos app, why?
Sample of my code:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *menuVC = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.image"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

[image]

Comment: Firstly, your title says "now", not "not".

Comment: hehehe sorry :) fixed that

Comment: I'm assuming it's also not in "More..."

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if there is another way natively to do this, but I came up with a solution to add a custom option with handler. I added "Photos" option and in the handler I use `UIImagePickerViewController`:

```
 UIDocumentMenuViewController *menuVC = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:UTIs inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];


    [menuVC addOptionWithTitle:@"Photos" image:nil order:UIDocumentMenuOrderFirst handler:^{

        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

I will do the same and add another option for "Camera".

Comment: Hi, First of all great thing that you have done.
How to get the response when a photo is selected, does it come to the callback of the DocumentPicker.show() like in the official example? Because I did the same thing as you but didn't receive callback. thanks

Comment: Callback with the selected photo will be there by conforming to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Comment: No it is not coming to the callback. Don't we have to implement the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo for the UIImagePickerController? I'm struggling to get some data (uri, fileSize, fileName) there from the selected image and return.

Comment: yes `didFinishPicking..` should help. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate