# Get the event of menu selection in uidocumentPickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have implemented `UIDocumentPickerViewController`  in my class.implemented delegate methods.

I want to know how would I know which option from `documentPickerMenu` i have selected. I want to implement the dropbox selection in the presented menu of document controller. I want to know it from delegate method.

the methods are as below

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {

    let cico = url as URL
    print("The Url is : \(cico)")
}

func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    print(documentMenu.accessibilityLabel ?? "Menu")
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func documentMenuWasCancelled(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController) {

    print("we cancelled")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

if anyone can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also add optional items to either the top or bottom of this list by calling the 'addOptionWithTitle:image:order:handler:' method. If the user selects one of these items, the system calls its handler.

Comment: @Ashish will you please provide method? i want perticular event fire on the tap of dropbox

Comment: refer stack link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127225/why-photos-app-is-not-showing-in-the-document-provider-extensions-on-the-device

Comment: @Ashish i dont want to add custom menu because in which ever device dropbox is installed the menu is having two times "dropbox" option. i only want to show the login page of dropbox on the click of default dropbox menu option.